# What to do when you have low app space for Android 4.1 or up?

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

You may have already removed all possible apps that are not useful to you, But your Android phone still keeps saying **insufficient memory** and can't install anything because of low app space available. What will you do?

Comment: Hm, I'd go visit our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for further hints :)

Comment: Answering your own question is welcomed on this site, but not if you're just posting a duplicate of questions that were already answered.

Answer (score 1):

I will show you two methods to free up app's space. I personally like Method 2 more because, it gives more freedom in choosing what to delete and what not to.

**Method 1: Clear cached Data**

- Go to Settings > Storage > Clear cached data (for all)

**Method 2: Using Storage Analyzer & Disk Usage app (Requires Android 4.1 or up)**

1. If you can't install anything from the start, I suggest to first uninstall apps that doesn't necessarily contain essential app data--one that you don't mind losing data for when you uninstall it, e.g., Facebook and Messenger apps (uninstalling any of them is actually enough). The app is only about 4 MB in size.
2. Install [Storage Analyzer & Disk Usage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobile_infographics_tools.mydrive&hl=en) app
3. Open the app called **Drives** (this is the app's name in my phone).
4. Wait for it to finish its scanning.
5. Go to the **DEVICE'S STORAGES** tab.
6. Click **Applications**, then wait for it to finish it’s scan.
7. Go to **FILE CATEGORIES** tab and delete all deletable stuffs except stuffs of the same type of App data.

   - **App cache** is usually what you want to delete.
   - **App apk** is usually undeletable, but it's just all the app apks you downloaded from the first time you got the cellphone, so it would be good if you are able to delete this. (As an aside, you can also comment to this answer how will I be able to do that).
   - I repeat, DO NOT DELETE **App data** or other folders of the same type because they're your app data.
   - **Note:** If you are able to delete a folder or a file, that file will be immediately deleted, no questions asked. **So be careful.**
8. Reinstall the apps you installed in the first step.

Comment: Happens :) As a hint from an "old-timer" to a "new-comer": Many of our tags have wikis assigned (easy to find: click the tag, then "info"), often with useful summaries and details. Especially for such common issues we've already "amassed" information. Always worth checking. Help on completing those details of course is welcome, as Dan already pointed out :) So after a somehow "bumpy start": have a good stay here. Drop into [our chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android-enthusiasts) if you need "a quick hint" on something.

Comment: Thanks @Izzy for being a good mod :) However, I can't really add my answer to that wiki because I still don't have enough rep for it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Please understand we'll keep this closed as duplicate nevertheless, as the linked question covers this already. Don't let that discourage you (we're all constantly learning new things each day), keep the spirit up :)

Comment: Okay! At least someone will still be able to see my answer, and hopefully get enough rep to be able to post answer there :)

Comment: PS:  And I didn't mean to add your answer to that wiki (as said, that hint is already part of another answer) – but in general to share especially missing parts in answers. We "old-timers" usually link especially useful things there then (we don't want to overload those wikis either, or they stop being useful). Once you've got a good feeling for a specific area (tag) on this site, you're of course welcome there, too – but that means being really familiar with what's already around here and how to "join it / sum it up" to the best benefit. Takes some time.